# Script to get URL and TCM of every localised page with a specific schema and CT

Tags: 2011, vbscript, tom

I need a script to  return the URL and TCM of every localised page with a specific schema based component on it and using a specific component template.

This is what I am trying to get a list of all the pages in a particular SG, But I get error:

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
Dim objTDSE
Set objTDSE = CreateObject("TDS.TDSE")
objTDSE.Initialize

Dim objSG As Object
Set objSG= lObjTDSE.GetObject("tcm:12-110069-4")


Dim lObjRowFilter
Set lObjRowFilter = ObjTDSE.CreateListRowFilter() 
Call lObjRowFilter.SetCondition("ItemType", 64)
Call lObjRowFilter.SetCondition("Recursive", True)


Dim doc
Set doc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
doc.async = false
doc.ValidateonParse = False
doc.resolveExternals = False

doc.LoadXml(objSG.getlistitems(15, lObjRowFilter) )
doc.save "D:\temp\Content Extract\SR3741354\PageList\ICP_CompList.xml"


If err.number <> 0 Then 
   MsgBox "Error : " & err.description
End If
MsgBox "Done !!"

set doc = Nothing
```

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: Object Required.

Comment: Did you try the answer I gave you here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12269/how-to-retrieve-the-list-of-localised-components-based-on-a-particular-schema-us ? Removing 15 for getlistitems call

Comment: yes, this script works fine for components with "15" but not for structure groups